# Very poor internet connection and drops on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet

After some update on my Ubuntu 22 LTS, I've got my wired internet connection to behave very strange. At first, it was fine but after few minutes it becomes to dissappear like I have no internet connection - my speed becomes 2-3 Mbps (while on Windows its 8-9 Mbps) and then becomes 0 Kbp/s (things like using git via terminal could tell about that, and internet comes back to normal after few minutes and so on...).

I'm having my internet connected to my TP-LINK Archer AX1500 router, which is connected to my computer. I also have Windows 10 on another SSD disk on this PC, which is having no issues like this with internet, but it seems only Ubuntu has.

My `lshw -C network` output:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 11
       serial: d8:bb:c1:61:4d:9e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=6.2.0-26-generic duplex=full firmware=0.6-4 ip=192.168.0.183 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:124 memory:a3300000-a331ffff
```

I have tried several things like:

- reinstalling Ubuntu
- updating router software
- disabling **wifi.powersave** mode in **NetworkManager** config
- turning the system from **Balance** to **Performance** mode
- setting **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off apm=off"** (the thing is that i had very huge lags with these values)
- `sudo apt-get install linux-oem-20.04`
- changing MTU to 1500, 1400, automatic...

I can say that Ubuntu was working fine after I've once updated from 20 to 22, but after some update on 22 version it got the behavior like this. Very terrible internet experience...
Could it be because of some kernel issues? Maybe a kernel downgrade is required? Please help!

Comment: why not download the iso for 23.04 and try that under `Try Ubuntu` selection to see if it improves matters.